# Java Program to simplify fractions not working.

Tags: java, fractions, simplify, greatest-common-divisor

I am trying to write a program that will take two fractions from the user (in the form a/b) and put them through certain manipulations and simplify the results. I've been able to get the math right, but I'm am having no luck with the simplifying part. I've been getting ArithmeticExceptions whenever I run the program.

Can anyone point me in the right direction and provide some feedback on my code?

Any advice is welcome and appreciated!

Main Class:

```
    import java.util.*;
    public class Fraction {

        /**
         * @param args
         */
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        public static void main(String[] args) {

            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Please enter your first fraction:");
            String frac = input.nextLine();
            Driver f1 = new Driver(frac);

            System.out.println("Please enter your second fraction:");
            String frac2 = input.nextLine();
            Driver f2 = new Driver(frac2);

            Driver multiFrac = f1.multiply(f1, f2);
            System.out.println("Multiplication: " +multiFrac.getNum()+ "/" + multiFrac.getDenom());

            Driver divFrac = f1.divide(f1, f2); 
            System.out.println("Division: " + divFrac.getNum()+ "/" + divFrac.getDenom());

            Driver addFrac = f1.add(f1, f2);
            System.out.println("Addition: " + addFrac.getNum()+ "/" + addFrac.getDenom());


            Driver subFrac = f1.sub(f1, f2);
            System.out.println("Subtraction: " + subFrac.getNum()+ "/" + subFrac.getDenom());


        }


    }
```

Constructor Class:

```
    public class Driver {

        public static int num0;
        public static int denom0;
        private int denom = 0;
        private int num = 0;

        public Driver (String frac){

    String s0[] = frac.split("/");

    int[] numbers0 = new int[s0.length];
    for(int i = 0;i < s0.length;i++){

        numbers0[i] = Integer.parseInt(s0[i]);
    }

    num = numbers0[0];
    denom = numbers0[1];
}

public Driver(int num0, int denom0) {
    num = num0;
    denom = denom0;
}

public int getNum(){
    int gcf= GCD(num0, denom0);
    return (num/gcf);
}

public int getDenom(){
    int gcf = GCD(num0, denom0);
    return (denom/gcf);
}


public Driver add(Driver firstFrac, Driver secondFrac){
    int denom0 = firstFrac.getDenom() * secondFrac.getDenom();
    int num0 = firstFrac.getNum() * secondFrac.getDenom() + secondFrac.getNum() * firstFrac.getDenom();
    this.GCD(num0, denom0);
    return new Driver (num0 , denom0);
}

public Driver sub(Driver firstFrac, Driver secondFrac){
    int denom0 = firstFrac.getDenom() * secondFrac.getDenom();  
    int num0 = (firstFrac.getNum() * secondFrac.getDenom()) - (secondFrac.getNum() * firstFrac.getDenom());
    return new Driver (num0 , denom0);
}

public Driver multiply(Driver firstFrac, Driver secondFrac){
    int num0 = firstFrac.getNum() * secondFrac.getNum();
    int denom0 = firstFrac.getDenom() * secondFrac.getDenom();
    return new Driver (num0, denom0);
}

public Driver divide(Driver firstFrac, Driver secondFrac){
    int num0 = firstFrac.getNum() * secondFrac.getDenom();
    int denom0 = firstFrac.getDenom() * secondFrac.getNum();
    this.GCD(num0, denom0);
    return new Driver (num0, denom0);
}

public int GCD(int a, int b){
       if (b==0) return a;
       return GCD(b,a%b);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a hint, use BigDecimal

```
String str[] = frac.split("/");

BigDecimal top = new BigDecimal (str[0]);
BigDecimal bottom= new BigDecimal (str[1]);

BigDeimal result = top.divide (bottom);
```

see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#divide(java.math.BigDecimal)

Comment: `BigDecimal` isn't that helpful for fractions. `new BigDecimal(1).divide(new BigDecimal(3));` throws an exception.

Comment: yeah, read the javadocs, and consider using a rounding mode.  I will trying to illustrate to the OP that it ain't such a good idea to require standard java classes.